# iTunes Sandbox Purchasing Not Allowed at This Time

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, appstore-sandbox

I'm developing an app with in-app purchasing and I am getting this error:

> You are not authorized to make purchases of this InApp in Sandbox at this time.

**I am sure I have everything set up correctly.** I've made sandbox accounts for purchasing the items. I have my code intact (thanks to *Ray Wenderlich*), and I'm pretty sure everything else is in order. But something must not be right.

**What could be causing this error?**

**EDIT:**

I'm working on the Xcode Simulator.

Comment: Are you correctly logged in to the simulator?

Comment: Yes, I even tried deleting the stuff from ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Library/com.apple.itunesstored so I can refresh login.

Comment: same error occurs on device too.

Comment: can't work on Simulator, do it on devices

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Chances are you are using provisioning profile from different developer account. In my case, products were registered with clients developer account and I was using my own developer account to test the app.

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple iTunes Connect accounts, make sure that your test user accounts exist in the same iTunes Connect account as the app.

Answer (score 1):

Your iTunes test user might also have been deleted.  Deleted users can apparently still log in but no longer make purchases.